# How to block access to an image from certain urls in my website?

Tags: html, http, https, server, uri

I have a website with multiple embedded images...

On the server side I store many versions of the same image (for sizing, etc.)

e.g. image.jpg, image-thumb.jpg, image-original.jpg

However I also keep a copy of the original, unedited image which contains sensitive information that I would like to keep away from public access. As it stands, if someone edits my  source from "**image.jpg**" to "**image-original.jpg**" they can see the original, which is a security risk.

I keep these original images so that they can be used in my custom backend CMS portal to edit the images as needed.

Is there a way to **prevent** access to the original? Perhaps by blocking loading of the original images folder unless the request is coming from certain locations on my website?

Comment: There is, but this concerns server configuration, and depends on the server you are using. I believe [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) will provide some answers for you

Comment: If your server has a directory structure like this: `/var/www/mysite/public`, then you can configure, say Apache, so that only files inside `public` are browser accessible. Then you can put your jpg files inside the `mysite` directory. They would then be inaccessible from people's browsers. However, your CMS which might be password protected and inside public could access the jpg files with say PHP and display them on your CMS. I think you would need to get the configuration of Apache and your directory and file permissions correct but I think it would work. I have to admit I have not done it!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured it out.

I added a `deny all` .htaccess file for the subdirectory that my images are stored in.

Then I served all images through a php script like this:

```
    // open file in binary mode
    $filename = 'img/'.$GET['img'];
    $imagefile = fopen($name, 'rb');

    // send the right headers
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));

    // dump the picture and stop the script
    fpassthru($imagefile );
```

Then it was easy to implement any logic I wanted, in order to prevent certain files from being opened. In this case I just did:

```
    if(strpos($_GET['name'], 'original')!=false){
        die();
    }
```

We can also include any logic needed to make sure that an admin user is logged in, etc...